# How to read every first line from a file as values, second as key to a dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a text file using every second line as the key and every first line as a list of values:

```
value1 value2
key1
value3 value4
key2
```

My code:

```
file = open('path', 'r')
my_dict = {}
a = 0
for lines in file:
    a += 1
    if ((a % 2) == 1):
        key_lines = lines.strip().split()
    else:
    value_lines = lines.strip().split()
    break
my_dict[key_lines] = value_lines[1]
```

doesn't work :(

Comment: So what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Put a print statement in the for loop suite to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a next line from the file by using the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
my_dict = {}
with open('path', 'r') as file_object:    
    for values in file_object:
        values = values.split()
        key = next(file_object, None)
        if key is None:
            # oops, we got to the end of the file early
            raise ValueError('Invalid file format, missing key')
        my_dict[key.strip()] = values
```

Each time you call `next()` on the file object the file returns the next line, and the `for` loop picks up again from that point. Thus, the `for` loop gets all the odd lines, with the values, the `next()` call then fetches the even lines, with the key.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot that there's also a every 3rd row blank, but I got it working with your sample.